# "keyof typeof" on Generics

Tags: typescript

Hello I have some struggle with my generic typing.

```
interface ReturnValue {
    keyA: string,
    keyB: string
}


interface FilterA {
    keyA: boolean;
}

interface FilterB {
    keyB: boolean;
}


const func = function<T>(args: T) : Pick<ReturnValue, keyof typeof args> {
    const res :Pick<ReturnValue, keyof typeof T> = {};
    Object.keys(args).map(key => {
        res[key] = key
    }) 

    return res;
}

console.log(func({keyB: true}).keyB); // should work
console.log(func({keyA: true}).keyA); // should work

console.log(func({keyA: true}).keyB); // should not work
console.log(func({keyC: true}).keyC); // should not work
```

But I have this error:

```
Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof ReturnValue'.
  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof ReturnValue'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof ReturnValue'.
      Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type '"keyB"'.
        Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"keyB"'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"keyB"'.(2344)
```

Any ideas ?

When I'm using the function call it's working fine, I can access only to what I gave as arguments but TS still display this error.

The context is GraphQl. My input is an object where value of each keys is `true` or `false`. From this object I'll build a GQL string query, fetch to api, and the return will have the same structure but value wont be `boolean` but `string` for example.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0+mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS+ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCwQyCjIyQYS0eOfxnFZ0HYKAA3ooSiV4pA8BV8ldUJROMxeAvF8u8AAhddUrfMRQAX2CigH32HSwAYpjB1V54vQAe1+N4HKPJwANyXv22x3iOKBPtAg6HqAb77iux7fr+ZiAVe5KNFSOJcLAPKYeY9SNAAPDgAB8KpkMwBTeDqoDrrQ7oEWOqATlOM78AeRKoO0RKOBRxEwaAKi0fRjHMQw05ZuxqQkXuJQyjQBI0XRsDxAx44mixEkrhxXFSXxvKzhegHvsm0gAFaQLAqABAeghkRROoBIgDAEEqB48nxsHviUBIANoHgAujhB4yaAF7UcE75OExJolvoKFoZSv4KvAyrJFhSqzgeCGbjOYXWfBOr-gJYD2BwLZNmQ0wyklipKml5gZZ+645ZAeWfoVxVXJgZWuBV0zSuhNUpXV6WZSuX4tW1BVFSopVRK4AzdOK0xAA)

Comment: Given that appears to just be a shallow copy, why is the return type not also T?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Input are boolean, output are string.

Comment: Well I simplified the code to expose the problem the returned value come from an api call

Comment: What exactly should `Pick` do in that example? For example, what if T has `keyC` prop?

Comment: Oh I see, it's just a map to the property's name. What's the point of that? To make it work you need to _constrain T_, but it's unclear what the context and purpose are. Should it be only the keys with true value, for example?

Comment: The context is GraphQl. My input is an object where value of each keys is `true` or `false`. From this object I'll build a GQL string query, fetch to api, and the return will have the same structure but value wont be `boolean` but `string` for example.

Comment: @raina77ow It should not be possible

Comment: You'd need to [edit] the question to explain, but what you have now just returns e.g. `{ keyA: "keyA" }` and it's not clear why that's useful. You need to read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints - T can currently be _anything_, so the compiler can't guarantee its keys will all be in ReturnValue.

Answer (score 0):

It wort using `Array.prototype.reduce` and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) here:

```js
interface FilterA {
    keyA: boolean;
}

interface FilterB {
    keyB: boolean;
}

type Filters = FilterA | FilterB

type Reduce<Obj> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Prop
}

const func = <Obj extends Filters>(args: Obj) =>
    Object.keys(args).reduce((acc, key) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: key
    }), {} as Reduce<Obj>)

func({ keyB: true }).keyB; // ok
func({ keyA: true }).keyA; // ok

func({ keyA: true }).keyB; // error
func({ keyC: true }).keyC // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m05lPW)

I have used immutable version of this approach not because it is better. I just prefer immutable data structures.

**UPDATE**

Code example of alternative version of `Reduce` from comments:

```js
type Reduce<Obj> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Prop extends keyof ReturnValue ? ReturnValue[Prop] : never
}


interface ReturnValue {
    keyA: string,
    keyB: string
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, i'll look deeper at it but I forget to precise a use case.
`func({ keyC: true }).keyC;` should no be possible, but in your case it's working

Comment: Made an update 1 min ago

Comment: big thanks to you this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Well it's almost done after investigation it should be something like that:
```
type Reduce<Obj> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: ReturnValue[Prop]
}
```
Where ReturnValue is:
```
interface ReturnValue {
    keyA: number,
    keyB: string
}
```
[Link](shorturl.at/txCZ0)

Comment: Link is broken. Feel free to provide your solution

Comment: Try this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaSgQWQbwChkTkBrCATxwC5kAjAe0YwjhAG5CBfQw0bPCRpM2AEIFipCpTF0mLNpx58B0ISnRZok0uSq0GzVuy56Zco4tMrCYSgAcUAJQgATAK5IAPAHl6AFYAfMgAvLqkANoAClCMDsig+pSMMMj+AQC6dK5gHlAgAGpwGB4QMXEOmbb84OqILhB5BcWlKETmBnQAzmBQoADmADRSJBY9fYO2CIwgvcgwHiAIYch+gcgQAB6QIG7dyNFwUGDAJd5a2EFBABTHA910GQCUOe5eEOvBYSFExFBNfIgZA1QiLZY3fDJSx9MrIbjPAB0Fg4yAA9GjkIwyGClghIclDLCUAjkQZURisTjwfj8ONkMTSRY+DTITIAMJ0RnPQhAA

Comment: @MorganDubois your example has several ta errors

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to fix. The type input and type output are different but key are the same. EG: input: {keyA: boolean} / output: {keyA: number}

Comment: @MorganDubois is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NddQdN) what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes exactly, 1000 thanks